# How do I fix my screen resolution?

Tags: graphics, resolution, screen

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.4 (not a VM). I have my display for my monitor at a full 1080p (which it supports). All icons and images look amazing. Everything is crisp. My display is currently at 1920x1080 (16:9), but my monitor isn't completely "fullscreen". I'm missing about 1 inch around every corner.

Potentially I could "downgrade" my resolution to 1680x1050 (16:10), but this does not fix the issue I'm having. The only thing I could think of myself (I just started using Ubuntu 2 days ago) is to somehow force a 16:10 aspect ratio. This probably is such an easy fix for experienced people.

Please and thank you for answering.

Comment: Ok, first of all, can you provide us a detail about your graphic card and what type you are using (typical AMD Radeon use VESA). Second, Can you reconfirm the screen resolution? We know your screen can support 1080p, but nowadays some monitor is in 3k mode (in between 4k2k and 1080p).

Comment: Close-voters: "This problem cannot be reproduced" is typically for problems where no one knows what solved it or where the solution is very unlikely to ever apply to anyone again. That doesn't seem to be the case here. This seems like a perfectly good, self-answered question that does not need to be closed. But if you still believe it *should* be closed, I'd encourage you to comment explaining why.

Answer (score 2):

Figured out the problem. It was an overscan/underscan issue with my display in the Catalyst Control Center. I fixed the issue by going to display manager, expanding it, then going to DTV adjustments. Set overscan to max. Problem fixed!!!!